# Constructing a URL for execution using RestTemplate

Tags: java, performance, url, rest, atomic

I am working on a project in which I construct a URL with a valid hostname (but not a blocked hostname) and then execute that URL using `RestTemplate` from my main thread. I also have a single background thread in my application which parses the data from the URL and extracts the block list of hostnames from it.

If any block list of hostnames is present, then I won't make a call to that hostname from the main thread and I will try making a call to another hostname. By block list, I mean whenever any server is down, its hostname is on the block list.

Here is my background thread code. It will get the data from my service URL and keep on running every 10 minutes once my application has started up. It will then parse the data coming from the URL and store it in a `ClientData` class variable.

```
public class TempScheduler {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        public void startScheduler() {
            final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        callServiceURL();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }

    // call the service and get the data and then parse 
    // the response.
    private void callServiceURL() {
        String url = "url";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        parseResponse(response);

    }

    // parse the response and store it in a variable
    private void parseResponse(String response) {
        //...       
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryTables = null;
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryTables = null;
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiaryTables = null;

        //...

        // store the data in ClientData class variables if anything has changed  
        // which can be used by other threads
        if(changed) {
            ClientData.setMappings(primaryTables, secondaryTables, tertiaryTables);
        }

        // get the block list of hostnames
        Map<String, List<String>> coloExceptionList = gson.fromJson(response.split("blocklist=")[1], Map.class);
        List<String> blockList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : coloExceptionList.entrySet()) {
            for(String hosts : entry.getValue()) {
                blockList.add(hosts);
            }
        }

        // store the block list of hostnames which I am not supposed to make a call
        // from my main application
        ClientData.setBlockListOfHostname(blockList);
    }
}
```

Below is my `ClientData` class in which I am using `CountDownLatch` -

```
public class ClientData {

    public static class Mappings {
        public final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary;
        public final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary;
        public final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary;

        public Mappings(
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary,
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary,
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary
        ) {
            this.primary = primary;
            this.secondary = secondary;
            this.tertiary = tertiary;
        }
    }

    private static final AtomicReference<Mappings> mappings = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final CountDownLatch hasBeenInitialized = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // do I need this extra AtomicReference?
    private static final AtomicReference<List<String>> blockListOfHosts = new AtomicReference<List<String>>();
    // do I need this extra latch here?
    private static final CountDownLatch hasBeenInitializedBlockHostnames = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static Mappings getMappings() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
            return mappings.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void setMappings(
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary,
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary,
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary
    ) {
        setMappings(new Mappings(primary, secondary, tertiary));
    }

    public static void setMappings(Mappings newMappings) {
        mappings.set(newMappings);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }

    public static void setBlockListOfHostname(List<String> listsOfHostnames) {
        blockListOfHosts.set(listsOfHostnames);
        hasBeenInitializedBlockHostnames.countDown();
    }

    public static boolean isExceptionHost(String hostName) {
        List<String> blockHostList = blockListOfHosts.get();

        if (blockHostList != null) {
            return blockHostList.contains(hostName);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main application thread code in which I find all the hostnames on which I can make a call and then iterate the `hostnames` list to make a call.

If that `hostname` is `null` or in the block list, then I won't make a call to that particular hostname and will try the next hostname in the list.

```
@Override
public DataResponse call() throws Exception {

    List<String> hostnames = new LinkedList<String>();

    Mappings mappings = ClientData.getMappings(); 
    // use mappings.primary 
    // use mappings.secondary 
    // use mappings.tertiary

    // .. some code here

    for (String hostname : hostnames) {     

        // If host name is null or host name is in block list category, skip sending request to this host
        if (hostname == null || ClientData.isExceptionHost(hostname)) {
            continue;
        }

        try {
            String url = generateURL(hostname);

            response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

            break;
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            // log exception
            // how to add this hostname in the block list as well in `ClientData` class?
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need to make a call to the hostname whenever it is down from the main thread. And my background thread gets these detail from one of my services, whenever any server is down. It will have the list of hostnames and whenever they are up, that list will get updated.

- Do I need extra `CountDownLatch` for block list of hostname in `ClientData` class or not?
- Do I need extra `AtomicReference` for block list of hostname as well or not?

This code will be called at a rate of 1000 requests per second so it has to be fast. For the first time, whenever my `blockListOfHosts` is being updated from the background thread, I can return false instead of blocking the call using `CountDownLatch` but it has to be atomic, all the threads should see correct value of the block list of hostnames.

And also, whenever any `RestClientException` is being thrown, I will add that hostname in the `blockListOfHosts` as well since my background thread is running every 10 minutes so that list won't have this hostname until 10 minutes is done. And whenever this server came back up, my background will update this list automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For adding and removing single host names, I would use a simple [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) without the `AtomicReference`. Initialize it with an empty map and drop the additional latch.

**Update:** I really doubt you need to replace the list of hosts all at once, but here's the combined form anyway:

```
private static final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> blockedHosts = 
        new AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>());

public static boolean isHostBlocked(String hostName) {
    return blockedHosts.get().containsKey(hostName);
}

public static void blockHost(String hostName) {
    blockedHosts.get().put(hostName, hostName);
}

public static void unblockHost(String hostName) {
    blockedHosts.get().remove(hostName);
}

public static void replaceBlockedHosts(List<String> hostNames) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> newBlockedHosts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    for (String hostName : hostNames) {
        newBlockedHosts.put(hostName, hostName);
    }
    blockedHosts.set(newBlockedHosts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In my case, `hostNames` list will have only three or four entries at a time maximum and minimum it will be zero. Let me edit my question with the code basis on your suggestion. I would probably go with the last option of `AtomicReference` but in that case, do we really need `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Go with the first part of my answer, then. The concurrent hash map will be better than replacing the map each time.

Comment: I see. But in that case, it won't be atomic operation right? And some threads might see inconsistent data? And also in the concurrent hash map key and value they both are same thing in your suggestion?

Comment: That's correct, but will that matter? If so, you must do the replace-at-once with the atomic reference. Always ask the question "What precise level of atomicity is required?" The reason for using a map with key/value same is to simulate a set which doesn't exist in `java.util.concurrent`. This is what `HashSet` and friends do under the hood.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Makes sense now. It's good to know some of the internals of the data structures. I have updated the question with your suggestion of `AtomicReference`. Can you take a look whether I got everything right or not? There might be some silly mistake I guess.

Comment: In your above example if I need to use `AtomicReference` then how would I be using it? In my another question what I posted earlier, it was not compiling when I tried in my eclipse. So I guess they way I used AtomicReference with ConcurrentHashMap was not right so got confuse. And you were  right it didn't compiled at all. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you around? Any suggestions, how can I make the above `replaceBlockHosts` method to deal with the `AtomicReference`. I tried doing it and I was not able to make it work.

Comment: @Webby I added the atomic reference. You just need to call `get` on it to access the underlying map. Call `set` to replace it with a new map. This is just like your previous question.

Comment: Aahh. I did the same thing then why it was not compiling for me. Later on I added `get` on the map call but still there was some compilation issues. Anyways, with your suggestions, I am seeing Compilation issue on this line `private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, String>> blockedHosts = new AtomicReference<>(
     new ConcurrentHashMap<>());` and the error is coming as `Type mismatch: cannot convert from AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Object>> to AtomicReference<Map<String,String>>`. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Oh right, change `Map` to the full concurrent version class name.

Comment: I already tried that and same error `private static final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> blockedHosts = new AtomicReference<>(
     new ConcurrentHashMap<>());` and the error is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Object>> to AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>`

Comment: Then you probably must specify the generic types (are you using Java 7+?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14614/discussion-between-webby-and-david-harkness).

Comment: Now it's working somehow with generics but I am using JDK 1.7 already. Pretty strange..

Comment: I made some final changes in my code. I started using HashSet along with AtomicReference and I created a new question for that [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51484/is-my-below-code-thread-safe-w-r-t-all-the-main-application-threads-should-get-c). Let me know if you see any issues in the code. Somehow, I was thinking ConcurrentHashMap was little overkill with key and value as same always. I might be wrong as I am still learning.

Comment: As I explained above, `HashSet` use a `HashMap` under the hood. Ordinarily this is an improvement, but because you're modifying the values from another thread, using the nonconcurrent version is *not* thread safe. You will be bitten eventually.

Comment: I see and I guess that is the reason, you have concurrenthashmap solution instead of hashset? Right?

Comment: Yes. You need the atomic reference for when you replace the entire set, and you need a concurrent collection for the add, remove, and is-blocked cases. There's no getting around this unless you are willing to drop the replace-set requirement with the non-atomic form I posted originally. Please read _Java Concurrency in Practice_ for a deeper understanding of thread safety and safe publication. It's tricky in the simplest of cases. Once you add conflicting requirements, things progress in difficulty rather quickly..

Comment: I have already started reading the same book you suggested me once I started working on multithreading perspective. It's been I guess five or six days. In any case, I can use your solution in this question as compared to my `HashSet` solution and your solution will be guaranteed thread safe and I can use it safely? Right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out and being patient in answering all my doubts. In my other code review [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51484/is-my-below-code-thread-safe-w-r-t-all-the-main-application-threads-should-get-c) which uses  your suggestion, one person is saying, it is not thread safe operation and we might require synchronization in `blockHost` method? Is that true, so far whatever I have read from the book you have suggested, it looks to me we don't need it.

Comment: hey david are you around. Have basic question on this suggestion you gave me long time back.